# type validation for higher order components

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, mixins, flowtype, higher-order-components

The question is basically is how to ensure type-checking with [higher-order components](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/ef0bf1f338a7182b6775) implemented in a typical JavaScript way.

```
Hoc1 = (superclass) => class extends superclass { ... }
class A { ... }
class B extends Hoc1(A) { ... }
```

By type-checking I mean using any of two most prominent utilities: [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) or [flow](https://flow.org/).

So far I have come up with the following snippet in TypeScript,

```
interface IAMixin {
  aMixedMethod(): void
}
interface IAMixinConstructor {
  new(): IAMixin
}

const AHoc: <T>(superclass: T) => T & IAMixinConstructor = (superclass) =>
  class extends superclass implements IAMixin {
    aMixedMethod() {}
}

class A {
  aMethod() {}
}
class B extends AHoc(A) {
  bMethod() {}
}

const b = new B();

b.aMixedMethod(); // false-positive: incrorrectly reports as missing method
b.aMethod();
b.bMethod();
b.cMethod(); // this is correctly caught, though
```

If I wrote the mixin this way

```
const AMixin: (superclass) => typeof superclass & IAMixinConstructor =
  (superclass) => class extends superclass implements IAMixin {
    aMixedMethod() {}
  }
```

then it thinks of `superclass` as `any` and false-negatively misses an error with the call of `cMethod`.

This seems to be possible at least in TypeScript, cause they have e.g. `Object.assign` correctly working for *instances*. But I need the construction of the same kind, but for *classes*.

Or do we need class types like [Ruby classes](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Class.html)?

Comment: See the [TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html) for the recommended pattern.

Comment: I’ve found https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2017/05/26/typescript-2-2-mixin-classes easier to read about new TS features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what was missing was defining the `AHoc` parameter as of constructor function type for the class instead of an actual instance and the same for the returned value:

```
interface IAMixin {
  aMixedMethod(): void
}

const AHoc: <T>(superclass: new () => T) => new () => (T & IAMixin) =
    (superclass) => class extends superclass implements IAMixin {
        aMixedMethod() { }
    }

class A {
  aMethod() {}
}
class B extends AHoc(A) {
  bMethod() {}
}

const b = new B();

b.aMixedMethod(); // now good
b.aMethod();
b.bMethod();
b.cMethod(); // this is correctly caught
```

Comment: I have found that introducing an alias `type Class<T> = new () => T` and using it makes code much more readable.